# Make a modal QDialog minimize when QMainWindow minimized (using PyQt 5)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Example code I am using:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.open_about = False
        self.openAction = QtWidgets.QAction('About', self)
        self.openAction.triggered.connect(self.aboutDialog)
        menuBar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menuBar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(self.openAction)
        self.calendar = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.calendar)

    def about_state_upd(self, value):
        self.open_about = value

    def aboutDialog(self):
        self._about = AboutDialog(self)
        self._about.exec_()

    def hideEvent(self, hideEvent):
        if self.open_about == True:
            self._about.setVisible(False)

    def showEvent(self, showEvent):
        if self.open_about == True:
            if self._about.isHidden() == True:
                self._about.setModal(True)
                self._about.setVisible(True)

class AboutDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(AboutDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setMinimumSize(400, 350)
        self.parent().about_state_upd(True)

    def closeEvent(self, closeEvent):
        self.parent().about_state_upd(False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app_window = MainWindow()
    app_window.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This code basically works, but seems very complicated.  Is there a simpler / cleaner way to make it so that when the modal QDialog is open, if the QMainWindow is minimized, the QDialog also gets minimized too (and reverse when QMainWindow is restored)?

Code is running on KDE Neon (Kubuntu-based distro).

Comment: For me, it works fine without all the `*Event()` overrides. A modal dialog should automatically stay in sync with its parent window. (NB: tested on archlinux with openbox window manager).

Comment: If the About is modal, how can you minimize the main window: at least on Windows, main window won't respond to any actions (like minimize, maximize, close, etc) if a modal dialog is executing. If I make the About dialog non-modal in your code (call show() instead of exec() on it), minimizing the main window also minimizes the About dialog (as ekhumoro commented), and restoring one restores both.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks for your feedback.  I have also now tried running the code (without any of the *Event() overrides) on xfce and (as you both say) it works as it should.  So it is clear now this a KDE bug - Kubuntu 16.04 LTS, Arch with KDE and KDE Neon stable all have the same problem.  I'll write a bug report for pyqt and / or KDE in the morning.

Comment: @poetofzwan. So what is the exact behaviour you see in KDE without the `*Event()` overrides? Is it like the Windows behaviour that Schollii described?

Comment: @ekhumoro If you run the application, open the QDialog and then minimize the QMainWindow - nothing happens to the QDialog.  It is just left on the screen (doesn't minimize).

Comment: @poetofzwan. Is the dialog still modal on the parent? If it is, I can reproduce the behaviour by omitting the parent for the dialog (but obviously your dialog *does* have a parent). Try the following test: in the dialog's show event, do `print(repr(self.windowHandle().transientParent()))`. If it's `None`, you could try putting `self.windowHandle().setTransientParent(parent.windowHandle()))` in the dialog's `__init__`.

Comment: @poetofzwan. It might also be worth editing your question and adding the output from a utility like `xprop`, which will show all the window manager hints. I think the problem may be that kde is not setting the `WM_TRANSIENT_FOR` hint properly.

Comment: @ekhumoro WM_TRANSIENT_FOR is set on the modal dialog and the id it is set to seems correct (i.e. its the id for the Main window).

print(repr(self.windowHandle().transientParent())) returns <PyQt5.QtGui.QWindow object at 0x7f6107332f78> which presumably is the main window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the people on the PyQt Mailing list, I managed to get a workaround for KDE.  Instead of using exec_(), I am just using show() - then I use setDisabled() on QMainWindow to make dialog act in a modal fashion.  Here is a (very quick and basic) example for anyone interested:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.openAction = QtWidgets.QAction('About', self)
        self.openAction.triggered.connect(self.aboutDialog)
        menuBar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menuBar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(self.openAction)
        self.calendar = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.calendar)

    def aboutDialog(self):
        self._about = AboutDialog(self)
        self.setDisabled (True)
        self._about.show()

    def enableWidgets(self):
        self.setDisabled(False)

class AboutDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(AboutDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setMinimumSize(400, 350)

    def closeEvent(self, parent):
        self.parent().enableWidgets()

    def changeEvent(self, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.WindowStateChange:
            if self.windowState() & QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimized:
                self.parent().showMinimized()
            else:
                self.parent().showMaximized()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app_window = MainWindow()
    app_window.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Link to [PyQt Mailing List posts](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2016-December/038463.html).

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use this: http://korbinin.blogspot.fr/search/label/minimize%20button

```js
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
 
 
class MainForm(QDialog):
 
    def __init__(self, fn=None,parent=None):
        super(MainForm, self).__init__(parent,\
           flags=Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint|Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint)
```